# Twitter Timeline widget not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter

My Twitter Timeline widget won't load in Chrome, but loads in both Firefox and IE perfectly.
When I check the console for Chrome, I get "Failed resource: http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" but when I click on that link, it works.

This is the code I am using:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/funnelholic"  data-widget-id="307229764530339840">Tweets by @funnelholic</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

I have also whitelisted both www.funnelholic.com and funnelholic.com

The site in question is: http://funnelholic.com, this is a Wordpress site, and I am using the Text widget to display it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can see it's on your page using `Chrome Version 25.0.1364.97 m`.

Comment: The Twitter widget works for me in Chrome 25.0.1364.99. I do notice that there are some errors in the console, but nothing that seems directly related. Have you tried clearing your cache and viewing the page?

Comment: Weird, I actually tested with v25.0.1364.97 too...also tested with Canary 27.0.1424.0, and cleared cache. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went home and tried it on a different computer in the same Chrome versions. Guess it somehow wasn't getting rid of cache...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and was very frustrated that it did not work in Chrome.

It seems that the reason was

[image] **Adblock Plus**

When I deactivated Adblock Plus for my page, it worked!

Guess you, @theintellects, also had Adblock active on the computer it did not work on.

With that said, I have added information on my webpage, that if the user uses Chrome and they don't see any Twitter timeline, they need to deactivate Adblock Plus for this [page](http://www.pixic.se/page_twitterflow.php)

Comment: For me it was Firefox's "Enhanced tracking protection". Adding the site as an exception worked.

Answer (score -2):

you need to add this script

```
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: Hi Haitam. Please consider explaining why adding the script would fix the issue, that would make your answer more complete and helpful.

Comment: I edited your post - you can indent code with four spaces to format it as code.